# Ending a Hailstone Sequence (Java)

Tags: java, arraylist

For my class,  I have to write a program where we have to create a Hailstone sequence from any number
(Hailstone is a math theory where if you divide even numbers by 2 and multiply odd numbers by 3 and add 1, then you will eventually end up with an endless pattern of 4,2,1,4,2,1)

My prompt is to cut the program off after it reaches two sequences of 4,2,1,4,2,1. Currently my code runs and I can cut it off at one sequence of this pattern. However, I am having trouble figuring out a loop to stop it at the end. My question is, did I set the code up so that I won't be able to catch this second sequence?

Code:

```
Scanner inData = new Scanner(new File("test.txt"));
    ArrayList<Integer> list= new ArrayList<Integer>();

    while(inData.hasNext())
            {
                int num=inData.nextInt();
                int var=list.size();
                list.add(num);

                while(num>1)
                {
                    if(num%2==0)
                    {
                        num/=2;
                        list.add(num);


                    }

                    else
                    {
                        num=(num*3)+1;
                        list.add(num);
                    }
                }


                System.out.print(list);
            }

}
```

Output with text input of 10 should be: 
    [10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1]
Currently:
[10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend writing a method that returns true when your list ends in 4,2,1,4,2,1:

```
private boolean finished(List<Integer> list) {
    int len = list.length();

    // check for minimum of 6 entries
    if(len < 6) {
        return false;
    }

    return list.get(len-1) == 1
        && list.get(len-2) == 2
        && list.get(len-3) == 4
        && list.get(len-4) == 1
        && list.get(len-5) == 2
        && list.get(len-6) == 4;
}
```

Then change your while loop to be:

```
while(num>1 && !finished(list)) {
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you! The only thing I changed was the second part of your suggestion and !finished, I had to delete num>1 because that was stoppping eclipse from printing it twice

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're asking how you can check a sequence of numbers in the list you are building.

This can be done in a number of ways. Probably the simplest is just searching for the pattern in the list you are are building.

```
static final List<Integer> PATTERN = Arrays.toList(4, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1);
if (Collections.indexOfSublist(list, PATTERN) >= 0) {
    ...
}
```

This isn't terribly efficient - it does an exhaustive search each iteration. I can't imagine that will be a problem for you but if it is then use `List.subList` to just search the last `PATTERN.size()` elements.

Comment: PATTERN should be 4, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1.

Comment: Thanks - good point. Also changed to use Collections utility to make it a bit simpler.

Answer (score 0):

That's right. Try this, which I think will work:

```
Scanner inData = new Scanner(new File("test.txt"));
ArrayList<Integer> list= new ArrayList<Integer>();

while(inData.hasNext())
{
    int num=inData.nextInt();
    int seq = 2
    list.add(num);

    while((num>1)&&(seq>0))
    {
        if(num%2==0)
        {
            num/=2;
            list.add(num);
        }
        else
        {
            if(num==1){
                seq -= 1;
            }
            num=(num*3)+1;
            list.add(num);
        }
    }

    System.out.print(list);
}
```